# Click event triggered on element but failing to toggle the visibility of the section containing it

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, ejs, visibility

I need to **toggle** a section (called "newHexagon")'s **visibility** by alternatively clicking two different h2's, "seeHexagon" and "hideHexagon". The former is external, **the latter (the one that is not working) internal to the section itself**. When the page is loaded newHexagon's visibility is hidden. If seeHexagon is clicked, it is correctly changed to "visible". The problem is that when hideHexagon is clicked, nothing happens, instead of visibility being brought back to hidden as required by my code. **The click on hideHexagon is correctly received**, as proven by console.log('clicked'), **but the next line of code (toggling visibility) simply seems to have no effect.**
My script is as follows

```
// retrieve element that when clicked fires the click event
const seeHexagon = document.getElementById('creaServizi');

// extract necessary html from a data attribute of body
const htmlServices = document.body.getAttribute("data-esagonoServizi");

// select the node to which append the new section
const servicesSide = document.querySelector('.terzaRigaDes');

// create the new section with visibility hidden
const newHexagon = document.createElement('section');
newHexagon.setAttribute('class', 'esagono esagonoServizi');
newHexagon.setAttribute('id', 'sezioneServizi');
newHexagon.style.visibility = 'hidden';

// fill the new section with html extracted above
newHexagon.innerHTML = htmlServices;

// append the new section to the selected node
servicesSide.appendChild(newHexagon);

// now that the section is present, retrieve the element that when clicked must fire the second click event
let hideHexagon = document.getElementById('chiudiServizi');

// add listener for click event to element that sets the new section's visibility to visible
seeHexagon.addEventListener('click', function () {
  newHexagon.style.visibility = 'visible';
  hideHexagon.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('clicked'); // EVERYTHING WORKS UP TO THIS LINE INCLUDED
    // NEXT LINE IS INEFFECTIVE AND THAT'S THE PROBLEM
    newHexagon.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  });
});
```

**Please note that the exact same result is obtained if the second event listener function is moved outside and below the first click's function.**

**Please also note that IT Goldman's solution below works here in the snippet provided as an answer, while in my webpage it does not, although the structure of that code chunk is the same: the second listener receives the click, but does not toggle the visibility. Is this a possible bug with JS scripts in an ejs file?**

**Please also consider that the h2 to be clicked to toggle visibility, shifting it to hidden, is not present in the DOM from the beginning but contained in a section that is created and added within the script.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the hide event listener outside of the other event listener, otherwise it will keep adding event listeners. (other than that the code is ok)

```js
// retrieve element that when clicked fires the click event
const seeHexagon = document.getElementById('creaServizi');
// extract necessary html from a data attribute of body
const htmlServices = "hello world";
// select the node to which append the new section
const servicesSide = document.querySelector('.terzaRigaDes');
// create the new section with visibility hidden
const newHexagon = document.createElement('section');
newHexagon.setAttribute('class', 'esagono esagonoServizi');
newHexagon.setAttribute('id', 'sezioneServizi');
newHexagon.style.visibility = 'hidden';
// fill the new section with html extracted above
newHexagon.innerHTML = '<button id="chiudiServizi">hideHexagon</button><br><br>'
  + htmlServices;

// append the new section to the selected node
servicesSide.appendChild(newHexagon);
// now that the section is present, retrieve the element that when clicked must fire the second click event
let hideHexagon = document.getElementById('chiudiServizi');
// add listener for click event to element that sets the new section's visibility to visible
seeHexagon.addEventListener('click', function() {
  newHexagon.style.visibility = 'visible';

});
hideHexagon.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('clicked'); // EVERYTHING WORKS UP TO THIS LINE INCLUDED
  // NEXT LINE IS INEFFECTIVE AND THAT'S THE PROBLEM
  newHexagon.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
```

```html
<button id="creaServizi">seeHexagon</button>


<div class="terzaRigaDes" style="margin-top: 20px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 20px;"></div>
```

Comment: As I wrote: "Please note that the exact same result is obtained if the second event listener function is moved outside and below the first click's function."

Comment: Yes you wrote it but but this snippet works.

Comment: Also, in your snippet the hideHexagon button is external to the element whose visibility needs to be toggled, while in my code it is not and must not be.

Comment: Then the button should be part of `newHexagon`. See `innerHTML` line.

Comment: The h2 to be clicked is indeed a part of newHexagon. In fact it receives the click.

Comment: Answer updated already

Comment: Since my reputation is not high enough to chat, I answer here. The snippet IT Goldman provided here shows the effect that I want to obtain. However, by replicating the code in my ejs file's js script, it does not work: the second listener receives the click, but does not toggle the visibility. Could this be a bug of js scripts in an ejs file or does it probably relate to the dom's structure?